# For loop in Maxima for matrix making

Tags: loops, for-loop, matrix, maxima

I want to make 3x3 M matrix using for loop. eq[] and Acc[] are arrays. Instead of getting 3x3 matrix , I am getting 1x9 Array which I don't want to get.

```
for f:1 thru 3 step 1 do(
    for r:1 thru 3 step 1 do(
    M[[r],[f]]:ratcoef(eq[r],Acc[f]))
);
listarray(M);
(%o22)  [3*l[1]^2*m[3],3*l[1]*l[2]*m[3]*cos(r[2](t)-r[1](t)),(3*l[1]*l[3]*m[3]*cos(r[3](t)-r[1](t)))/2,3*l[1]*l[2]*m[3]*cos(r[2](t)-r[1](t)),3*l[2]^2*m[3],(3*l[2]*l[3]*m[3]*cos(r[3](t)-r[2](t)))/2,(3*l[1]*l[3]*m[3]*cos(r[3](t)-r[1](t)))/2,(3*l[2]*l[3]*m[3]*cos(r[3](t)-r[2](t)))/2,(3*l[3]^2*m[3]+12*Theta[3])/4]
```

Somehow I have to mention a symbol to indicate that new row is starting, I tried to put ; but it ends the for loop immediately and causes problem.
 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

When you assign something to `M[i, j]` without declaring `M` previously, Maxima creates an array (called an "undeclared array" in Maxima terminology) attached to the symbol `M` as a property, not a value. Therefore when you input `M` in the interactive prompt, you see only `M` because it doesn't have a value. (Properties are items which are associated with a symbol, which are distinct from the value of the symbol.)

With that preamble, I will recommend that you assign a matrix value to `M` and then assign to the elements of the matrix. I don't have the definitions of `eq` and `Acc` so `ratcoef` doesn't do anything useful here.

```
(%i4) M : zeromatrix (3, 3);
                           [ 0  0  0 ]
                           [         ]
(%o4)                      [ 0  0  0 ]
                           [         ]
                           [ 0  0  0 ]

(%i6) for f:1 thru 3
        do for r:1 thru 3
          do M[r, f] : ratcoef(eq[r],Acc[f]);
(%o6)                         done
```

Note that the subscripts are just `r` and `f`, not `[r]` and `[f]`. In general `[x]` is a list of 1 element, namely `x`.

There are other ways to accomplish this, if it turns out this doesn't work so well for you.

Comment: Actually, this looks a good way to approach the problem, your effort is highly appreciated. I will try it now, and give feedback something is wrong